# How can I reset my Windows 10 computer without login

Tags: windows-10, factory-defaults

I have a Windows 10 laptop and I do not know the correct password. How can I factory reset everything and log in?

*Background*:

I have been using the laptop for a couple of years with a separate SSD running Linux; the Windows SSD is still there but unused. I don't have access to any Windows installation media or any Windows laptop. I don't know my password as I have been using Linux since I got the laptop. I am not trying to recover the account for which I have lost my password, just to make a new account as I need to use Windows-only software.

*Notes*:

- The two SSDs in my laptop are physically separate
- The Windows one is running "Windows 10 Pro", if that makes any difference.
- All my data is on the Linux one, I don't care at all about anything on the Windows one. I am happy to completely factory reset everything.

Comment: If you use a Microsoft Account (default in the last few years), go to Microsoft Live, to your email address (the one you used for the Microsoft Account and reset the password,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here that you can still boot Windows, but just don't have the password to login.

The simplest method is to use from Linux the `chntpw` command which should be in
your Linux distribution. See the tutorial at
[How to reset a Windows password with Linux](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/how-reset-windows-password-linux)
(discard the parts that don't pertain to your case).

An alternative hack is to use Linux to modify the Windows disk
(NTFS support may need the `ntfs-3g` package), where you could:

- Position to `\Windows\System32`
- Rename `sethc.exe` to `sethc.exe.bak`
- Copy `cmd.exe` to `sethc.exe`
- Boot Windows and at the login screen hit the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key 5 times
  to get into an administrator mode command prompt
- Enter the command `net user USER-NAME NEW-PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not restore windows it is posible without it follow below given link video for win 8,10,11 password reset
https://youtu.be/xg8TZeXnsUE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There are various methods to reset your windows 10 without password:

1. use Windows installation disk to replace ultiman.exe or sethc.exe, you may refer to this article [how to reset windows password with command prompt](https://www.reneelab.com/bypass_windows_10_password_command_prompt.html)
2. use third party password reset disk , such as: [renee passnow](https://www.reneelab.com/system-rescue), [ophcrack](https://ophcrack.sourceforge.io/), and so on...